# Convert SimpleAudioEngine to AudioEngine Cocos2dx-v4

Tags: cocos2d-x-4.0

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->preloadEffect("Sounds/Hit.mp3");
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->preloadEffect("Sounds/Point.mp3");
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->preloadEffect("Sounds/Wing.mp3");
```

I make the gameclone with cocos2dx version 4.0 but I check in document of cocos2dx-v4, I see in Doc we can use SimpleAudioEngine and i try this code when I Debug the code say "SimpleAudioEngine unidentified ", How can i change to AudioEngine, Thanks for answer and reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try：

```
cocos2d::AudioEngine::preload("Sounds/Hit.mp3");
```